# What is difference between keyboard navigation in mac with Enable Full Keyboard Access

Tags: javascript, macos, keyboard, accessibility

I am trying to develop a custom UI which is keyboard accessible but noticed there difference in `Tab` key navigation

In the following jsfiddle example:

```js
let div1 = document.getElementById('1');
let div2 = document.getElementById('2');
let div3= document.getElementById('3');
let div4= document.getElementById('4');
let div5= document.getElementById('5');

div5.addEventListener('keydown', (evt)  => {
    console.log("keydown callback");
    evt.preventDefault();
    div1.focus();
});
```

```html
<div tabindex="0" id="1">Hello 1</div>
<div tabindex="0" id="2">Hello 2</div>
<div tabindex="0" id="3">Hello 3</div>
<div tabindex="0" id="4">Hello 4</div>
<div tabindex="0" id="5">Hello 5</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zp65h7j3
I am trying to move the focus back to div 1 when there is keydown on the div 5 and logging the event.

This is working as expected in mac.
But when enable full keyboard access the navigation is messed up. The keydown listener is also not executed.

Is this issue with mac when `Full Keyboard Access` is enabled